# ¿Como crear un contenedor para un archivo bash que corre un jar?

Tags: java, bash, docker, kubernetes

tengo una duda para crear un contenedor que corra una archivo bash.

Actualmente para correr un archivo bash que contiene la ruta de un jar es el siguiente:

**Carpeta de properties:** En esta carpeta guardo los archivos properties de todas las configuraciones de las variables que ocupa mi archivo jar

**Carpeta jar:** En esta carpeta guardo todos los jar ejecutables

**Carpeta bash:** Guardo todo los archivos bash que se ejecuta.

Como verán esta es la configuración que uso y tengo divido mi proyecto en 3 partes. Ahora necesito subir este flujo a un Kubernetes y para esto debo crear la imagen o el contenedor para poder correr un proceso de java que esta en un bash, pero no tengo idea si las 3 partes deben ir en una sola imagen o como seria? Me siento confundido.

Un ejemplo de lo que contiene mi archivo bash es lo siguiente:

```
/user/home/jars/MainCargaDocumentos.jar
/user/home/properties/cargaDocumentos.properties
```

Ahora solo necesito saber como seria para poder implementar este flujo en un Kubernetes, pero no se como seria, alguna sugerencia para este flujo?

se los agradecería mucho gracias

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes es un orquestador de contenedores, por lo tanto lo que debes hacer es contenerizar tu artifact o en tu caso tu jar, por ejemplo si utilizas docker puedes definir un dockerfile donde puedas ejecutar tus comandos necesarios, puedes verifiar [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) o [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) según sea tu necesidad.